# In SwiftUI, How do I make it so that when I click a button, the button background color changes to reflect if the answer is right or wrong?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on developing a quiz app. I have the following code, in two SwiftUI Views. Right now, the entire screen background color changes if you get an answer correct(to green)/incorrect(to red) but I want only the button background color to change, and the background of the screen to remain white. How do I implement this in the code?

Content View Swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let question = Question(questionText: "What was the first computer bug?", possibleAnswers: ["Ant", "Beetle", "Moth", "Fly"], correctAnswerIndex: 2)
    @State var mainColor = Color(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255)
    @State var textBackgroundColor = Color.white

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            mainColor.ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack{
                Text("Question 1 of 10")
                    .font(.callout)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.bottom, 1)
                    .padding(.trailing, 170)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                Text(question.questionText)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .bold()
                    .background(textBackgroundColor)
                    Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 200)
                VStack(spacing: 20){
                    ForEach(0..<question.possibleAnswers.count) { answerIndex in
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Tapped on option with the text: \(question.possibleAnswers[answerIndex])")
                            mainColor = answerIndex == question.correctAnswerIndex ? .green : .red
                            textBackgroundColor = answerIndex == question.correctAnswerIndex ? .green : .red
                            print(textBackgroundColor)
                        }, label: {
                            ChoiceTextView(choiceText: question.possibleAnswers[answerIndex])
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

ChoiceTextView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ChoiceTextView: View {
    let choiceText: String
    let accentColor = Color(red: 48/255, green: 105/255, blue: 240/255)
    @State var textBackgroundColor = Color.white
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(choiceText)
            .frame(width:250)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .padding()
        // make background white to put shadow later
            .background(textBackgroundColor)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .shadow(color: Color(hue: 1.0, saturation: 0.0, brightness: 0.869), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
    }
}

struct ChoiceTextView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChoiceTextView(choiceText: "Choice Text!", textBackgroundColor: Color.white)
    }
}
```

Please help me figure this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code does what you are trying to achieve.

Basically, avoid using the color to the main view's background and instead, put it in the button background modifier.
Also, instead of using the index of the array I use the value. I think it's easier to identify plus it avoids the ForEach warning that shows up for using a non fixed Int value.

```
struct Question {
    let questionText: String
    let possibleAnswers: [String]
    let correctAnswer: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let question = Question(
        questionText: "What was the first computer bug?",
        possibleAnswers: ["Ant", "Beetle", "Moth", "Fly"],
        correctAnswer: "Beetle"
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack{
                Text("Question 1 of 10")
                    .font(.callout)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.bottom, 1)
                    .padding(.trailing, 170)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                
                Text(question.questionText)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .bold()
                
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 200)
                
                VStack(spacing: 20){
                    ForEach(question.possibleAnswers, id: \.self) { answer in
                        ChoiceButton(
                            answer: answer,
                            question: question
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChoiceButton: View {
    let answer: String
    let question: Question
    
    @State private var mainColor = Color(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255)
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("Tapped on option with the text: \(answer)")
            mainColor = answer == question.correctAnswer ? .green : .red
        } label: {
            Text(answer)
                .frame(width:250)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding()
            // make background white to put shadow later
                .background(mainColor)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .shadow(color: Color(hue: 1.0, saturation: 0.0, brightness: 0.869), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]